# How do I write a trigger that only allows editing for certain fields when an Opportunity is Closed Won?

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity, validation

I have a list of a few fields that I want to be able to edit once an opportunity is Closed-Won.

A validation rule will not work for this, as it would require listing every single field that I do NOT want to allow editing for (which would run past the character).

In addition, I cannot use a declarative solution that changes the record type, as this would cause issues with pre-existing automation and reports.

Instead, I want a trigger that allows me to state which fields are allowed editing, else, don't allow the record to save.

What would an apex trigger for this look like?

TLDR;

An opportunity is Closed-Won. I do not want to allow editing of any fields, except for 5 of them. What would a trigger for this look like?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? If you're new to writing triggers, Trailhead is the [place to start](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers).

Comment: Welcome to SFSE - you can learn about our format at [ask] and [help/on-topic], which will help shape a question that will be received more positively by the community.

Comment: @DavidReed I've tried validation rules. I am currently stuck on how to write the trigger. I just need an overview of the logic involved and the specific types of methods needed to prevent a save if any field, except for the exception fields, are edited.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a simple trigger.

```
trigger preventChanges on Opportunity (after update) {
  Set<String> allowedFields = new Set<String> {
    'Field1','Field2','Field3','Field4','Field5'
  };
  for(Integer index = 0; index < Trigger.size; index++) {
    if(!Trigger.old[index].IsClosed && Trigger.new[index].IsClosed) {
      sObject beforeRecord = Trigger.old[index].clone(false, false, false, false);
      sObject afterRecord = Trigger.new[index].clone(false, false, false, false);
      Map<String, Object> oldValues = beforeRecord.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
      Map<String, Object> newValues = afterRecord.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
      oldValues.keySet().removeAll(allowedFields);
      newValues.keySet().removeAll(allowedFields);
      if(oldValues != newValues) {
        Trigger.new[index].addError('You cannot edit most fields when the opportunity is closed.');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What we do here is we clone the old and new versions to clear out autonumber fields, audit fields, etc, pull out the populated fields, remove the "allowed" changes so we don't compare those, and finally we compare the maps efficiently with `!=`. If there are any changes, we can report the error. You could go further and figure out which fields changed, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you, if you're interested.

Of course, there's also considerations for using a framework, using a Field Set or Custom Metadata to dynamically populate the allowed fields, etc, but this should serve as a basic stepping stone.

Answer (score 2):

Well, at a basic level, it would look and sound a lot like how you'd describe a validation rule. You'd need to check if any field other than your allowed fields (and system fields like `LastModifiedById` and `LastModifiedDate`) has changed.

If you're not already fairly well versed in code, this is going to be a lot more work than I imagine you think it is.

#### The basic parts of the code

In pseudocode

```
trigger MyObj on MyObj__c(before update){
    for every record in trigger.new {
        grab the corresponding record from trigger.oldMap

        for every field on MyObj__c{
            if oldRecord field value != newRecord field value && field is not on your allowList
                add an error to the record from trigger.new to prevent the DML
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Getting every field on an SObject means you'd be using the SObject describe information, or I suppose you could save yourself a little trouble and call `getPopulatedFieldsAsMap()` (a method provided by the SObject class).

The describe info approach would look something like

```java
// You could probably get away with using the keyMap() instead of using
//   values(), but going down to the Schema.FieldDescribeResult for each field
//   would allow you to check if the field is not updatable or if it's a formula
//   (two scenarios that should be excluded from a check to disallow changes)
for(Schema.SObjectField sobjField :MyObj__c.SObjectType.fields.getMap().values()){
    objectFields.add(sobjField.getDescribe().getName());
}
```

Tracking which fields are allowed to change could be done by hard-coding them, but a better approach there would be to declare and use a fieldset (which would allow you to make adjustments via the web UI without needing to re-deploy code).

Pulling in the fieldset in the trigger would require another loop like

```java
for(Schema.FieldSetMember fsm :MyObj__c.SObjectType.fieldsets.MyFieldSet.getFields()){
    allowedFields.add(fsm.getFieldPath());
}
```

The `getPopulatedFieldsAsMap()` approach would do away with the need for some of that, but at the cost of you needing to define (and keep up to date) a list of every field that is allowed or is not under your direct control (like formula fields and system fields).

#### Your job is not over yet

You still need to write a unit test (which should almost certainly have multiple test methods) to be able to deploy this trigger of yours. Not too hard in and of itself, but just another thing to add on to the list of things you'd need to do.

#### Honestly, take another look at record types

Using record types to manage this seems to me like it's the most appropriate approach to handling what you want to do.

You haven't gone into detail about this "other automation" you have, but I'd imagine it's not updating your `Opportunity` after it's closed-won (so that should be a non-issue). If it is, then the trigger approach is probably going to make things worse (i.e. require additional code to work around).

Fields marked as "read only" in page layouts are only enforced on the UI level. Things like workflow/flow/process builder field updates and triggers ignore that.

The point I'm trying to make here is that updating reports and other automation may end up being less effort than trying to develop a trigger to handle this.